# Why isn't my class being added to the logo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, solidus

I'm working on a project in Rails using Solidus and want to resize the logo I added in.  I've done it quite a few times successfully as I've started this project over numerous times but this time it's not resizing.  I checked the console and don't even see the class added to the element like I normally do.

first I had to create a helper file which looks like this

```
module Spree::BaseHelper
    def logo(image_path = Spree::Config[:logo], img_options: {})
      link_to image_tag(image_path, img_options), spree.root_path
    end 
end
```

then I tweaked the coding in the header partial that calls it up to look like this

```
<figure id="logo" class="columns six" data-hook>
    <%= logo img_options: { class: 'img-responsive', width: '281' } %>
</figure>
```

I also had to adjust a config file to link to the location of the logo which his working fine because it's showing up.  I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

Comment: I've thought over this multiple times and still can't figure it out. Are you getting any errors? Are you sure both the helper decorator and the adjustment to the header partial are in the right place, and are being included in the code that is actually being run? I see nothing wrong here as it is.